# How to duplicate each row in table and add new column with 2 different values

Tags: sql, string, oracle, cross-join

I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

I want to turn it to this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a `cross join` with a fixed list of values:

```
select p.*, p.product || v.val pk
from mytable t
cross join (
    select '20' val from dual
    union all select '50' from dual
) v
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the union all like so:

```
select t.product, t.qty, t.product || '20' pk from the_table t
union all
select t.product, t.qty, t.product || '50' pk from the_table t;
```